# Get all item be created in loop, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can I get all items been created in loop with ruby on rails?? Here my example:

```
@fb_data_hash = {:key1 => value1, :key2 => value2, :key3 => value3, ...}
@fb_data_hash.each do |key, val|
timeline = get_id_and_content(key, val)
  #timeline will be created like this:
    =>first:  timeline = {:id => "1", :content => "abcd"}
    =>second:  timeline = {:id => "2", :content => "efgh"}
    =>third:  timeline = {:id => "3", :content => "ijkl"}
end
```

So, I want to get all timeline each time it been created, like this:

```
alltimelines = [{:id => "1", :content => "abcd"},{:id => "2", :content => "efgh"},{:id => "3", :content => "ijkl"}]
```

<=>

```
alltimelines = [timeline(first),timeline(second),timeline(third)]
```

But, I don't know how to do that, I tried create an array like this:

```
alltimelines = Array.new
alltimelines << timeline
```

but, it just get one timeline in first. Please help me :)

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do. There are errors in your code. `@fb_data_hash = Hash` makes no sense.

Comment: Oh! it's just a example :). Hash <=> {:key1 => value1, :key2 => value2, :key3 => value3}. Nothing error with my code. Normally, I can creat timelines with my code, but I don't know how to collect all of them into one array(alltimelines) each time they been created

Comment: It's helpful if the code that you post is valid code, even if it is example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` for this purpose

```
some_hash = { key: "value", other_key: "other_value" }
some_hash.map do |key, val|
  get_id_and_content(key, val)
end
# => equivalent to [ get_id_and_content(:key, "value"), get_id_and_content(:other_key, "other_value") ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [`Enumerable#collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) which will return a new array by running a block on each item of the enumerable, but also it won't destroy or modify the old variable

```
timeline = @fb_data_hash.collect { |key, val| get_id_and_content(key, val) }
# @fb_data_hash is still intact
# timeline has the data that you want
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this format with an array like:

```
all_timelines = [{:id => "1", :content => "abcd"},{:id => "2", :content => "efgh"},{:id => "3", :content => "ijkl"}]
```

This code should do the trick (assuming the fact that @fb_data_hash actually contains data) :

```
all_timelines = Array.new
@fb_data_hash.each do |key, val|
  all_timelines.push({:id => key, :content => val})
end
```

Then you can call your array like that (as an exemple)

```
all_timelines.first # return {:id=>1, :content=>"abcd"}
```

Hope that is you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, but I must create timeline with get_id_and_content(key, val) method